# Not able to use UISegmentedControl with three tabs and ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, alpha

I made an iOS app with Xcode and Swift. I want to use UISegmentedControl with three tabs. With these tabs I can switch between three ContainerViews.

Which numbers do I have to input in the alpha fields? 0, 1 and 2? Because when I set 2 it always reverts back to 1. Why that? How can I do this?

This is the code I'm using to connect the tabs with the ContainerViews:

```
    @IBAction func switchSegmentedControll(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.segmentedControllFirst.alpha = 1
                self.segmentedControllSecond.alpha = 0
//                self.segmentedControllThird.alpha = 0
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                self.segmentedControllFirst.alpha = 0
                self.segmentedControllSecond.alpha = 1
//                self.segmentedControllThird.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you call "alpha field" the only thing I see is the transparency control (the view's alpha value)

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html

Comment: why you are setting the alpha value for other segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just found the solution. It was a misunderstanding by myself. I didn't know what `Alpha` is and how the code I'm using works.

This is the working code:

```
@IBAction func switchSegmentedControll(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.segmentedControllFirst.alpha = 1
            self.segmentedControllSecond.alpha = 0
            self.segmentedControllThird.alpha = 0
        })
    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.segmentedControllFirst.alpha = 0
            self.segmentedControllSecond.alpha = 1
            self.segmentedControllThird.alpha = 0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.segmentedControllFirst.alpha = 0
            self.segmentedControllSecond.alpha = 0
            self.segmentedControllThird.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have three tabs, then set the `Segments` field to '3' like shown in screenshot below:

[image]

alpha value ranges from 0 to 1 and is used for visibility. You cannot set the alpha value more than 1

Comment: You should accept Mohammed Shakeer's answer and post another question, not update this question if you have other problems